# Rating not choosing more than 3 stars - React Native Elements - Rating)

Tags: react-native, rating

I am using the Rating Element from the react-native-elements component. I noticed I can't choose more/less than 3 stars for my rating and I do not understand why.
Here is my code:

```
<Modal animationType={"slide"} transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.showModal}
                onDismiss={() => this.openModal()}
                onRequestClose={() => this.openModal()}>
                <View style={styles.modal}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Rating</Text>
                    <Rating
                        showRating
                        type="star"
                        imageSize={30}
                        onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
                        style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
                    />

                    <View style={styles.btnView}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => { this.handleFormSubmit() }}
                            color="#512DA8"
                            title="Submit"
                            style={styles.formBtn}
                        />
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => { this.openModal(); 
       this.resetForm(); }}
                            color="gray"
                            title="Cancel"
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to use **AirbnbRating** instead of **Rating** because it work for me.

Example code :

```
import {AirbnbRating } from 'react-native-elements';

<AirbnbRating
  count={11}
  reviews={["Terrible", "Bad", "Meh", "OK", "Good", "Hmm...", "Very Good", "Wow", "Amazing", "Unbelievable", "Jesus"]}
  defaultRating={11}
  size={20}
onFinishRating={rating => console.log(rating)}
/>
```

Comment: This gives ```Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required 'option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false```

Answer (score 0):

According to,

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/rating.html#ratingcount

you can use the prop `ratingCount` to set the number of rating images to display.
Try setting this to something other than 3.

**Edit**

Seems I misunderstood the query, please try setting `readonly` to `false` explicitly.

Comment: The ratingCount is 5. It is showing the 5 stars. The question is, it is not allowing rating less/more than 3 stars. I.e there are only 3 shaded stars no matter what star I click on

Answer (score 0):

I would ask what do you have in function

```
onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
```

I also used this component in my project and updated the state there:

```
        <Rating
          showRating
          startingValue={4}
          onFinishRating={rating => this.setState({ rating: rating })}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the rating component in a function that returns the rating:

**NOTE**: this is a little bit strange, but it worked for me

Change your code like the following:

```
const RatingView=()=>{
   return (
            <Rating
                showRating
                type="star"
                imageSize={30}
                onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
                style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
             />
   )
}
```

You Modal :

```
<Modal animationType={"slide"} transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.showModal}
                onDismiss={() => this.openModal()}
                onRequestClose={() => this.openModal()}>
                <View style={styles.modal}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Rating</Text>
                    <RatingView /> // Here ...

                    <View style={styles.btnView}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => { this.handleFormSubmit() }}
                            color="#512DA8"
                            title="Submit"
                            style={styles.formBtn}
                        />
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => { this.openModal(); 
       this.resetForm(); }}
                            color="gray"
                            title="Cancel"
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
```